# Validate user inputs before submit form

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have this code to validate inputs:

```
<script>
        function validate()
        {
            var firstName = document.form.fullname.value;
            var lastName = document.form.fullname.value;
            var email = document.form.email.value;
            var password = document.form.password.value;
            var conpassword = document.form.conpassword.value;

            if (firstName == null || firstName == "")
            {
                alert("Firstname  can't be blank");
                return false;
            } else if (lastName == null || lastName == "")
            {
                alert("Lastname can't be blank");
                return false;
            } else if (email == null || email == "")
            {
                alert("Email can't be blank");
                return false;
            } else if (password.length < 6)
            {
                alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And this is my form:

```
<form name="form" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/register" method="post">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="left">
                <div class="header">
                    <h2 class="animation a1">Register now</h2>
                    <h4 class="animation a2">Enter information in field and create account!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="form">
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-field animation a3" placeholder="Name...">
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-field animation a3" placeholder="Last name...">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-field animation a3" placeholder="Email adress...">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-field animation a4" placeholder="Password">
                    <button class="animation a6" value="Submit" type="submit">REGISTER</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

How to implement that function to my form? Because now when I click submit, in my database an empty user is added. I want to add that it throws out an error in each field if it is not validly filled in

Answer (score 1):

1. You can get the validate function to execute by adding an 'onsubmit' to your form html tag ( see here w3 Schools for executing a function on submit: [onsubmit in forms](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp))
2. As for the errors, when executing the code, the function cannot read a property 'value' of undefined.  So what is happening is that you are telling the validate function to get parts out of the form out that it cannot find (fullname and conpassword are not defined).

Take a look at your form's name tags for fields and then reference those names in the validate function.  So when declaring firstName instead of `document.form.fullname.value` try `document.form.firstName.value` referring in the form.  Do this for first and last name using their names in the form, and also get rid of (or comment out) the conpassword variable.

Answer (score 0):

This validation could be done without javascript function. Use the "required" tag for the inputs which are mandatory.
For example :

```html
<input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-field animation a3" placeholder="Name..." required>
```

In case of password you may use the pattern attribute.

If you need to use javascript in particular, then go for onclick in the button tag.

```html
<button class="animation a6" onclick="validate()">REGISTER</button>
```

and include the form submit in the javascript function -

```js
  document.form.submit();
```